# Why Podman can not inspect object? Error: error inspecting object: no such object: "docker://registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8"

Tags: linux, podman

I pulled it

```
podman pull docker://registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8
Trying to pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 0fa65fe5c23e done  
Copying config 817f060b46 done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
817f060b4672f886292b297d96d2288dec751013210f35a4c89cd9499866e7a5
```

If I go for inspect

```
podman inspect docker://registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8
[]
Error: error inspecting object: no such object: "docker://registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8"
```

why?

Comment: `docker://` is a string representing the transport. See  [podman pull man page](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-pull.1.html). If you remove `docker://` from the podman-inspect-command it works:  `podman inspect registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8`